# Android Studio : 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy, android-studio-3.3

I have installed [Android Studio Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) version since the stable IDE version does not support the JetPack that is being used in my application.

But I am facing proxy issue while syncing the project,

> ERROR: Could not GET
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
>   Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I have set proxy using both from Android studio settings and gradle.properties file,

**gradle.properties**

```
systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxxx
systemProp.http.proxyUser=xxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxxxx
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=xxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyHost=xxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyUser=xxxxx
```

Still project sync gives the same error. Any solutions?

**Studio Version :** Android Studio 3.3 Beta 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

There is a `gradle.properties` file under `.gradle` of home directory `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

where you need to enter your proxy password manually.

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyHost=xxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxxx
systemProp.https.proxyUser=xxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxxxx
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=xxxxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxxx
systemProp.http.proxyUser=xxxxx
```

Comment: This is perfect solution, I faced this error when I use flutter plugin in my company network, after setting as above, the error gone away. thanks so much